# apt upgrade has a ton of packages in the "kept back" state for weeks, so I'm stuck with the upgrade and don't know what to do

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu

When I try to do a upgrade using apt I get a message saying these packages have been kept back, but it's been like this for weeks.

> kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-config-screenlocker khotkeys
> khotkeys-data kscreen kubuntu-restricted-addons kwin-common kwin-data
> kwin-wayland kwin-x11 libcolorcorrect5 libk3b8 libkf5screen-bin
> libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5   libkscreenlocker5 libkwineffects14
> libkwinglutils14 libkworkspace5-5 libnotificationmanager1
> libnvidia-cfg1-525 libnvidia-compute-525 libnvidia-compute-525:i386
> libnvidia-decode-525 libnvidia-decode-525:i386 libnvidia-encode-525
> libnvidia-encode-525:i386 libnvidia-extra-525 libnvidia-fbc1-525
> libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 libnvidia-gl-525 libnvidia-gl-525:i386
> libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpowerdevilcore2 libpowerdevilui5
> libtaskmanager6 libweather-ion7   linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic
> nvidia-compute-utils-525 nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-kernel-common-525
> nvidia-kernel-source-525 nvidia-utils-525 plasma-desktop
> plasma-desktop-data plasma-workspace plasma-workspace-data
> plasma-workspace-wayland powerdevil powerdevil-data systemsettings
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525

I have checked the Phasing Ubuntu Stable Release Updates page [Phasing Ubuntu Stable Release Updates][1] page but it says nothing about those packages for kinetic.

It's annoying because I have an error in a graphical application using the OpenGL renderer, though Vulkan works, that started when I did my last upgrade and ran into this issue, so I think that may be related to the nvidia stuff being out of sync with the rest of the upgrades that went through due the driver being held back.

I can't use the Vulkan renderer though because of the crap code installation in the app, so Vulkan either runs like treacle at 1fps or I remove a gfx extension from the app to run at full fps but without most textures and models being rendered. So the Vulkan renderer works while at the same time not actually working.

And I have no idea what to do about this situation. Usually kept back packages resolve themselves, but like i said this has been weeks now and the phased update page says nothing about them.

Help?

Kubuntu: 22.10
Kernel: 5.19.0-31-generic (64-bit)

**EDIT:** As per @user535733 request this is the output form apt policy check for kde-cli-tools

```
  Installed: 4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
  Candidate: 4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
  Version table:
     4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.25.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 Packages
```

and for nvidia-driver-525

```
nvidia-driver-525:
  Installed: 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
  Candidate: 525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
  Version table:
     525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
 *** 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I have never had to look at policies before so no idea what this means for my issue apart from the fact I can see an obvious problem though no idea what the actual problem/solution is.
[1]: https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html?ref=itsfoss.com

EDIT 2: Here's the output of the apt full-upgrade

> Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state
> information... Calculating upgrade... The following packages were
> automatically installed and are no longer required:   aha
> appmenu-gtk-module-common appmenu-gtk3-module clinfo fonts-hack
> fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-ui-core
> fonts-noto-unhinted   haveged ibus-data kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kgamma5
> kwin-data   libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libcolorcorrect5 libhavege2
> libibus-1.0-5   libkdecorations2private9 libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5
> libkpipewire5   libkpipewiredmabuf5 libkpipewirerecord5 libksgrd9
> libkwineffects14   libkwinglutils14 libnotificationmanager1
> liboxygenstyle5-5   liboxygenstyleconfig5-5
> libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpowerdevilcore2   libpowerdevilui5
> libprocessui9 libqaccessibilityclient-qt5-0   libqalculate-data
> libqalculate22 libqt5hunspellinputmethod5   libqt5virtualkeyboard5
> libscim8v5 libweather-ion7 libxcb-dpms0   plasma-desktop-data
> plasma-integration plasma-thunderbolt   plasma-workspace-data
> power-profiles-daemon powerdevil-data   qml-module-org-kde-activities
> qml-module-org-kde-kholidays   qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem
> qml-module-org-kde-pipewire   qml-module-org-kde-solid
> qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard   qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin sddm
> vulkan-tools xwayland Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The
> following packages will be REMOVED   kde-config-screenlocker
> kinfocenter kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-settings-desktop   kwin-addons
> kwin-common kwin-wayland kwin-x11 libk3b7-extracodecs
> libkscreenlocker5 linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-31-generic
> plasma-desktop   plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace
> plasma-workspace-wayland powerdevil   sddm-theme-breeze The following
> NEW packages will be installed   libk3b-extracodecs
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-35-generic The following packages have
> been kept back:   kscreen libkf5screen-bin libnotificationmanager1
> libsnmp-base libsnmp40   xserver-common xserver-xorg-core
> xserver-xorg-legacy The following packages will be upgraded:   curl
> gir1.2-babl-0.1 gir1.2-gegl-0.4 grub-efi-amd64-bin
> grub-efi-amd64-signed imagemagick-6-common kde-cli-tools
> kde-cli-tools-data   khotkeys khotkeys-data kubuntu-restricted-addons
> kwin-data libbabl-0.1-0   libbabl-dev libcolorcorrect5 libcurl3-gnutls
> libcurl4 libgegl-0.4-0   libgegl-common libgegl-dev libk3b8
> libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5   libkwineffects14 libkwinglutils14
> libkworkspace5-5 libldap-2.5-0   libldap-common libmagickcore-6.q16-6
> libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra   libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libnetplan0
> libnvidia-cfg1-525 libnvidia-compute-525   libnvidia-compute-525:i386
> libnvidia-decode-525 libnvidia-decode-525:i386   libnvidia-encode-525
> libnvidia-encode-525:i386 libnvidia-extra-525   libnvidia-fbc1-525
> libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 libnvidia-gl-525   libnvidia-gl-525:i386
> libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpowerdevilcore2   libpowerdevilui5
> libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpython3.10   libpython3.10-dev
> libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libtaskmanager6
> libweather-ion7 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic netplan.io
> nvidia-compute-utils-525 nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-kernel-common-525
> nvidia-kernel-source-525 nvidia-utils-525 plasma-desktop-data
> plasma-workspace-data powerdevil-data python3.10 python3.10-dev
> python3.10-minimal python3.10-venv sddm systemsettings vim-common
> vim-tiny   xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525 xxd 75 to upgrade, 2 to newly
> install, 17 to remove and 8 not to upgrade. Remv
> kde-config-screenlocker [5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Remv
> kubuntu-desktop [1.426] Remv kinfocenter
> [4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Remv kubuntu-settings-desktop
> [1:22.10.4] Remv kwin-addons [4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Remv
> plasma-workspace-wayland [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Remv
> plasma-desktop [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Remv
> plasma-workspace [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv kwin-x11
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv kwin-common
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> kwin-wayland:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv kwin-wayland
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv libk3b7-extracodecs
> [22.08.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv libkscreenlocker5
> [5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst nvidia-driver-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-gl-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [libnvidia-gl-525:amd64 on
> libnvidia-gl-525:i386] [libnvidia-gl-525:i386 on
> libnvidia-gl-525:amd64] [libnvidia-gl-525:i386
> plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> libnvidia-gl-525:i386 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic [5.19.0-31.32] (5.19.0-35.36
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-31-generic [5.19.0-31.32]
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> nvidia-kernel-common-525 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> nvidia-kernel-source-525 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> libnvidia-decode-525:i386 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386])
> [libnvidia-decode-525:amd64 on libnvidia-decode-525:i386]
> [libnvidia-decode-525:i386 on libnvidia-decode-525:amd64]
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 libnvidia-decode-525:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-decode-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-compute-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [libnvidia-compute-525:amd64 on
> libnvidia-compute-525:i386] [libnvidia-compute-525:i386 on
> libnvidia-compute-525:amd64] [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 libnvidia-compute-525:i386 ] Inst
> libnvidia-compute-525:i386 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> libnvidia-extra-525 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> nvidia-compute-utils-525 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> libnvidia-encode-525 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> [libnvidia-encode-525:amd64 on libnvidia-encode-525:i386]
> [libnvidia-encode-525:i386 on libnvidia-encode-525:amd64]
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 libnvidia-encode-525:i386
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-encode-525:i386
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst nvidia-utils-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-cfg1-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64
> sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst libnvidia-fbc1-525
> [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1] (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [libnvidia-fbc1-525:amd64 on
> libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386] [libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 on
> libnvidia-fbc1-525:amd64] [libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386
> plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 [525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1]
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Inst
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-35-generic (5.19.0-35.36
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [plasma-widgets-addons:amd64 sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv
> plasma-widgets-addons [4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> [sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv powerdevil
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] [sddm-theme-breeze:amd64 ] Remv
> sddm-theme-breeze [4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1] Inst
> python3.10-dev [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst libpython3.10-dev [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst libpython3.10 [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst python3.10-venv [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst python3.10 [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst libpython3.10-stdlib [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst python3.10-minimal [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst libpython3.10-minimal [3.10.7-1ubuntu0.2] (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Inst imagemagick-6-common [8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.2]
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [all]) Inst libmagickcore-6.q16-6
> [8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.2]
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Inst libmagickwand-6.q16-6
> [8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.2]
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Inst netplan.io
> [0.105-0ubuntu2] (0.105-0ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates
> [amd64]) [] Inst libnetplan0 [0.105-0ubuntu2] (0.105-0ubuntu2.2
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Inst xxd [2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1]
> (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Inst vim-tiny
> [2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1] (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst vim-common [2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1] (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [all])
> Inst libldap-2.5-0 [2.5.13+dfsg-1ubuntu1]
> (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> Inst curl [7.85.0-1ubuntu0.3] (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> [] Inst libcurl4 [7.85.0-1ubuntu0.3] (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Inst libbabl-dev [1:0.1.96-1] (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) [] Inst libbabl-0.1-0 [1:0.1.96-1]
> (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) []
> Inst gir1.2-babl-0.1 [1:0.1.96-1] (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Inst libgegl-common [1:0.4.38-1build1]
> (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [all])
> Inst libgegl-dev [1:0.4.38-1build1] (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP
> Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) [] Inst libgegl-0.4-0
> [1:0.4.38-1build1] (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) [] Inst gir1.2-gegl-0.4
> [1:0.4.38-1build1] (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Inst grub-efi-amd64-signed
> [1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14] (1.187.3+2.06-2ubuntu14.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [] Inst grub-efi-amd64-bin
> [2.06-2ubuntu14] (2.06-2ubuntu14.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates
> [amd64]) Inst kde-cli-tools [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) [] Inst kde-cli-tools-data
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) [] Inst libkworkspace5-5 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst khotkeys [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) [] Inst khotkeys-data [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Inst kubuntu-restricted-addons [26] (28~ubuntu-22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Inst kwin-data
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Inst libcolorcorrect5 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libcurl3-gnutls [7.85.0-1ubuntu0.3] (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Inst libk3b8 [22.08.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (22.12.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libk3b-extracodecs (22.12.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Inst libkfontinstui5
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) [] Inst libkfontinst5 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libkwineffects14 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) [] Inst libkwinglutils14 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libldap-common [2.5.13+dfsg-1ubuntu1]
> (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [all]) Inst
> libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra [8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.2]
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Inst
> libplasma-geolocation-interface5 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libpowerdevilcore2 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libpowerdevilui5 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libpulse-mainloop-glib0 [1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3]
> (1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) [] Inst
> libpulse0 [1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3] (1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Inst libtaskmanager6
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst libweather-ion7 [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Inst plasma-desktop-data [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Inst plasma-workspace-data [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Inst powerdevil-data [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Inst sddm [0.19.0-3ubuntu1.1] (0.19.0-3ubuntu1.2
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Inst systemsettings
> [4:5.26.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1]
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf nvidia-driver-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf libnvidia-gl-525
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnvidia-gl-525:i386 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) Conf
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic (5.19.0-35.36
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Conf nvidia-kernel-common-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf nvidia-kernel-source-525
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnvidia-decode-525:i386 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) Conf libnvidia-decode-525
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnvidia-compute-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf libnvidia-compute-525:i386
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) Conf
> libnvidia-extra-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf nvidia-compute-utils-525
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnvidia-encode-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf libnvidia-encode-525:i386
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) Conf
> nvidia-utils-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf libnvidia-cfg1-525
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnvidia-fbc1-525 (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386
> (525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [i386]) Conf
> linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-35-generic (5.19.0-35.36
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Conf python3.10-dev (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libpython3.10-dev
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libpython3.10
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf python3.10-venv
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf python3.10
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libpython3.10-stdlib
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf python3.10-minimal
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libpython3.10-minimal
> (3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf imagemagick-6-common
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [all]) Conf libmagickcore-6.q16-6
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libmagickwand-6.q16-6
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf netplan.io
> (0.105-0ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libnetplan0 (0.105-0ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> Conf xxd (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf vim-tiny
> (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf vim-common
> (2:9.0.0242-1ubuntu1.2 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [all]) Conf libldap-2.5-0
> (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64])
> Conf curl (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libcurl4
> (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf libbabl-dev
> (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf
> libbabl-0.1-0 (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf gir1.2-babl-0.1 (1:0.1.102-0build1~22.10 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libgegl-common
> (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [all])
> Conf libgegl-dev (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libgegl-0.4-0
> (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64])
> Conf gir1.2-gegl-0.4 (1:0.4.42-0build2~ubuntu2210 GIMP Image
> Editor:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf grub-efi-amd64-signed
> (1.187.3+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.06-2ubuntu14.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates
> [amd64]) Conf kde-cli-tools (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf kde-cli-tools-data
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Conf libkworkspace5-5 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf khotkeys
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf khotkeys-data (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [all]) Conf kubuntu-restricted-addons
> (28~ubuntu-22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf
> kwin-data (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu
> Backports:22.10/kinetic [all]) Conf libcolorcorrect5
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf libcurl3-gnutls (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.5
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates, Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64])
> Conf libk3b8 (22.12.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu
> Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libk3b-extracodecs
> (22.12.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf libkfontinstui5 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libkfontinst5
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf libkwineffects14 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libkwinglutils14
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf libldap-common (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [all]) Conf libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
> (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.10.3 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates,
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-security [amd64]) Conf
> libplasma-geolocation-interface5 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libpowerdevilcore2
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf libpowerdevilui5 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libpulse-mainloop-glib0
> (1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf
> libpulse0 (1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3.1 Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates
> [amd64]) Conf libtaskmanager6 (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [amd64]) Conf libweather-ion7
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64]) Conf plasma-desktop-data (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [all]) Conf plasma-workspace-data
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [all]) Conf powerdevil-data (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1
> Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic [all]) Conf sddm (0.19.0-3ubuntu1.2
> Ubuntu:22.10/kinetic-updates [amd64]) Conf systemsettings
> (4:5.27.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu22.10~ppa1 Kubuntu Backports:22.10/kinetic
> [amd64])

EDIT 3: As suggested by @user535733 and @popeye I disabled the backports PPA and did a *apt full-upgrade* which has resolved all the upgrade issues.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144752/discussion-on-question-by-nobody-special-apt-upgrade-has-a-ton-of-packages-in-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output shows that packages provided by the Kubuntu PPA conflict with other packages on your system.

There is no fast/easy/safe fix.

Your options:

1. Hope: You can wait for the Kubuntu PPA to catch up. It's possible (not guaranteed) that developers might cure the version conflict with a future upload.
2. Migrate from PPA-provided packages to stock Kubuntu. Backup your data first. This process will destroy your graphical desktop in order to save your whole system. This method works best for folks with an intermediate-level understanding of how sources and packages work, and are reasonably comfortable using a shell prompt.

   - Install yet another PPA
   - Install the `ppa-purge` application from that PPA
   - Use `ppa-purge` to remove the Kubuntu PPA and all packages installed from it.
   - Use apt to reinstall `kubuntu-desktop` from the stock Ubuntu repositories
3. Reinstall Kubuntu from a LiveUSB. Definitely backup your data first, as a mistake will wipe your storage device. For many users, despite the severity of the solution, this is the fastest and easiest way to a working system again.